# Как идемпотентно установить роль из Ansible Galaxy средствами ansible?

Tags: linux, администрирование, развертывание, ansible, ansible-galaxy

У меня есть роль, в задачу которой входит установка nodejs. Как **ещё один** вариант - я добавил поддержку установки через [snap](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#snap). Для этого мне надо фактически выполнить `ansible-galaxy install don_rumata.ansible_role_install_snap`. Можно использовать [command+creates](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html), но это больше похоже на быдлохак. Можно [git](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/git_module.html), но тогда теряется связь с galaxy. Слышал про `requirements.yml`, но в примерах не нашёл возможность использования `when`. В общем нужно что-то типа:

```yaml
- name: Install role "install-snap"
  when:
    - ansible_system == 'Linux'
    - nodejs_install_over_snap == true
  ansible_galaxy:
    name: don_rumata.ansible_role_install_snap
    state: present
  delegate_to: localhost
```

Comment: meta depends on? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#role-dependencies

Comment: Как я понял - это если у тебя роль уже установлена. А тут нет - надо её сначала вытащить с galaxy.

Comment: Да, извиняюсь. Думаю может добавить роль  в плейбук, которая ставит Галакси зависимости по условиям.

Comment: Ну. Это я и спрашиваю: как сделать, чтобы не через комманд.

Answer (score 0):

В документации есть возможность перечислить все зависимости в `requirements.yml` и потом **в ручную**, перед запуском основного плейбука, их подтягивать.

```
ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i inventory
```

Можно так же загнать это в таск и запускать как инициирующий в роли:

```
- name: Install roles from Ansible Galaxy
  command: ansible-galaxy install {{ item.item }}
  with_items:
    - "{{ ansible_roles_list }}"
```

**Ссылки**

- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/galaxy/user_guide.html#installing-multiple-roles-from-a-file
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230376/how-to-automatically-install-ansible-galaxy-roles

Comment: Ты не читаешь. Я же написал, что `Можно использовать command+creates, но это больше похоже на быдлохак.`